# What is default in chrome://flags

Tags: google-chrome

In Chrome flags some items have a drop down with 'default'. What does that mean?
Is it enabled or disabled? How can I tell?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of Quic, you can tell whether it's enabled by browsing to

```
chrome://net-internals/#quic
```

Comment: Learn something new everyday, this is nifty